# ¿Como puedo añadir a un campo text area ya creado un tag sin que me borre lo ya escrito?

Tags: javascript, html

verán tengo algo como

```
<textarea name="x" id="x">
```

y me gustaría ponerle un boton que me genere el tag

```
<a></a>
```

He pensado en algo como

```
var final document.getElemtById('x').value+
"<a href='aqui introduzca el link'>Aqui la palabra a móstrar</a>".
```

Comment: @lois6b también me sorprendió, no pensé en renderizar la etiqueta con el innerHTML ya que por lo que se ve en la pregunta no lo iba a necesitar

Comment: @Jorius pensaba que el poner etiquetas <a> era para que se renderizaran como enlaces. Pero si quiere texto plano, el `<a>` despista xDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById('x');

function addTag(){
  var current_value = textArea.value;
  var new_tag = "<a href='aqui introduzca el link'>Aqui la palabra a móstrar</a>";
  textArea.value = current_value + ' ' + new_tag;
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="x" id="x">
  Hola soy un textarea
</textarea><br />
<button onclick="addTag();">Add tag</button>
```

Comment: Hola, y como se implementaría en un formulário

Answer (score 3):

Con un textarea puedes añadir texto dentro pero no va a hacer render del HTML. Asi que te sugiero usar un div, con el atributo `contenteditable=true`:

Para hacer click en los elementos `<a>` de dentro, usé jQuery:

```js
function addA() {

  var textarea = document.getElementById("divEditable");
  textarea.innerHTML += "<a href='https://www.google.es/'>Google</a><br>";

}


$('#divEditable').on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target != this) {
    if(event.target.tagName == 'A')
      window.location = event.target.href;
  }
});
```

```css
div.editable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class="editable" id="divEditable"><a href='https://www.google.es/'>Google</a><br><a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>SOeng</a><br></div>


<input type="button" onclick="addA();" value="añadir">
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Pero no es lo que busco. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Ah, pensaba que el poner etiquetas `<a>` era para que se renderizaran como enlaces. buscabas meramente el texto entonces?

Comment: Si, disculpa por la confusión.

Comment: Nada, sin problemas. eso me pasa por presuponer ^^